# Failed to install clangd language server in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, clangd

I'm using VScode and my workspace is on a remote linux server. I successfully installed `clangd` extension on the remote server, however when I tried to download the language server, I get the following error:

```
Failed to install clangd language server: FetchError: request to https://api.github.com/repos/clangd/clangd/releases/latest failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.github.com You may want to install it manually.
```

I have not been able to find a related question on this. Could someone advise what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

first, install clangd manually: `sudo apt-get install clangd`.
then, `ctrl+shift+p` to 'clangd: Check for language server update'.